# Pandas - drop unique rows if there are less than N

Tags: python, pandas

One of my column (city) in pandas dataframe look like:

```
0           city1
1           city1
2           city2
3           city1
4           city5
5           city2
...
```

Occurrence of individual cities:

```
city3         6758
city32        6400
city1         4500
city13        2440
...
```

I want to remove cities that occur less than n times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do `transform`

```
N=10
newdf=df[df.groupby('city')['city'].transform('count')>N].copy()
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what you want exactly I would either use:

```
import pandas as pd
threshold=7
cities = ['city1' for _ in range(10)] + ['city2' for _ in range(5)]
df = pd.DataFrame(cities, columns=['city'])
df['freq'] = df.groupby('city')['city'].transform('count')
df = df[df['freq']>threshold]
```

which keeps all the rows in the original df

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df['city'].value_counts())
df = df[df['city']<threshold]
```

which would give you only one row per city name.

Answer (score 1):

Merge your city dataframe with the city count dataframe on the city column, loc on occurrences >= threshold should give you what you’re looking for

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly get how your dataframe is organized, but it should be as simple as

- `df[df['unique count'] < n]` or `df[df['unique count'] >= n]`
  (depends on what you want)

You might have to play around with the syntax on this piece of code just because I don't fully understand your dataframe, **but** this should work for what you need it for.

Hope this helps!!